# Is it possible to access a cookie and not have it sent in request headers?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to set a cookie in a client's computer, use JavaScript to access the cookie, but not have it sent in HTTP request header, like:

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=r6osuqd20m72ho45lf5lohohe6; sum=csfftak5jf8gjffsp3el93g2a2
```

Comment: Sounds like you _actually_ need HTML5 local storage, and [a nice library to use it](http://www.jstorage.info/). That your question is tagged "cookies" is an XY problem: you're asking about [what you wrongly think is] the solution, not about the actual requirement.

Comment: (_"jStorage is really small, just about 7kB when minified"_ lolwut)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am looking into it now.

Comment: If someone posts a storage engine I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: What I meant is if someone posts something like what has been posted in the comments I will accept it as the answer. I am not asking for people to post a local storage script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can probably use [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to achieve your goal. Whatever your goal is. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, cookies are always send to the server, with each request.